# The ability to download an d3.js overlay on a google map using html2canvas

Tags: jquery, google-maps, d3.js, html2canvas

For this one project, I have a user bringing up a Google map with a d3.js overlay on top of it.  Then the user should have the ability to download the map with the overlay as a .png file for their use. The problem is that the d3.js overlay is not appearing on the download. Note I have modified another fiddle with a Google map overlay since I am not permitted to show the actual data and map, but I have added the call to html2canvas to demonstrate my problem

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/japiasente/c9ag3jhu/)

```
     $("#btnClickHere").on("click", function() {
            //get transform value
            var transform = $(".gm-style>div:first>div").css("transform");
            var comp = transform.split(","); //split up the transform matrix
            var mapleft = parseFloat(comp[4]); //get left value
            var maptop = parseFloat(comp[5]); //get top value
            $(".gm-style>div:first>div").css({
                //get the map container. not sure if stable
                "transform": "none",
                    "left": mapleft,
                    "top": maptop,
            });
            html2canvas($("#map")[0], {
                useCORS: true,
                background: "#E8F0F6",
                onrendered: function(canvas) {

                    $(".gm-style>div:first>div").css({
                        left: 0,
                        top: 0,
                            "transform": transform
                    });

                    //     $this.appendChild(canvas);

                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.download = name;
                    a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();


                },
                width: 800,
                height: 500,
            });
        });
```

Comment: Your fiddle is broken: `Uncaught ReferenceError: html2canvas is not defined`

Comment: Hmm that is odd.  It seems to work for me, but anyways I set up a new version as the base [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/japiasente/c9ag3jhu/). I ran it and I didn't get the uncaught reference error

Comment: I'd imagine it's because your browser has the `html2canvas` cached.  Here's a version which fixes those links:  http://jsfiddle.net/c9ag3jhu/4/ (I used `https://rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.js`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SVG positioning is very strange:

```
.SvgOverlay svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4000px;
  left: -4000px;
  width: 8000px;
  height: 8000px;
}
```

My initial thought that it's just off the page.  Sure enough when you move it:

```
.SvgOverlay svg {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
 }
```

Give it appropriate size:

```
var svg = layer.append("svg").attr("width",500).attr("height",500);
```

And remove the strange re-positioning:

```
return [pixelCoordinates.x, pixelCoordinates.y];
```

It overlays in the png, updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c9ag3jhu/7/).

**EDITS**

Oh and one more thing, looks like you need to set the styles explicitly on the element to get them carried into the resulting canvas.  Update link above.

```
.attr("d", path)
.style("fill", "orange").style("stroke-width", 2).style("fill-opacity",0.3).style("stroke","orange");
```

Comment: I read that positioning from another stack overflow item was to handle problems with the overlay getting cut off if the user zooms in too much. But for this situation that works good enough.